# -Roll 2 Dices until gets SnakeEyes- What's wrong with my logic and how to print the last result of a method without caling it again

Tags: java

This is a homework in which I have to code 2 dices that roll constantly and only stop when both gets SnakeEyes. I'm having 2 issues:

1. Sometimes the CastDie1 and CastDie2 returns 1 but the IF statement doesn't validate the condition.
2. I want to print out every result, including the Snake Eyes, but whenever I try to print the SnakeEyes result, the method gets called again and the numbers change.

   ```
   public class SnakeEyesCount {

   /**
   * @param args the command line arguments
   * @return 
   */
   public static int CastDie1() {
       int die1 = (int)(Math.random()*6)+1;
       return die1;
   }

   public static int CastDie2() {
       int die2 = (int)(Math.random()*6)+1;
       return die2;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       // TODO code application logic here
       int countSnakeEyes = 0;
       boolean snakeEyes = false;

       while (snakeEyes == false) {
           TextIO.putln("Die1: " + CastDie1());
           TextIO.putln("Die2: " + CastDie2());
           countSnakeEyes++;
           if (CastDie1() == 1 && CastDie2() == 1) {
               TextIO.putln("Die1: " + CastDie1() + " SNAKE EYES!");
               TextIO.putln("Die2: " + CastDie2() + " SNAKE EYES!");
               TextIO.putln("Snake Eyes after " + countSnakeEyes + " rolls of the dice");
               snakeEyes= true;
           }
       }
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: Assign the results of the call to `castDie` to a local variable ... `int die1 = castDie1()`, then you can print and evaluate it without it changing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `CastDie1` and `CastDie2` twice.  Since the result is random you're not guaranteed to get the same value in consecutive executions.

Call the method ***once***, and store the result in a variable to be printed off and used otherwise.

```
while(!snakeEyes) {
    int die1 = CastDie1();
    int die2 = CastDie2();
    TextIO.putln("Die1: " + die1);
    // and so forth
    if(die1 == 1 && die2 == 1) {
        // the rest of your logic
    }
}
```

While I respect that having two distinct methods to invoke for die is what you want, they do the same thing so I would encourage you to collapse this down to a single method:  `castDie`.  I leave this as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: I did try to use just a single method but then I realized "oh I don't know how to return 2 values and I don't know how print out each of those values separately". Anyway, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Store the result of your method call in a variable. Print the value of the variables, then check if it's snake eyes.

Also, there is no need to have two separate CastDie methods; they do the same thing.